# Removing a certain class using jQuery upon hover within a Bootstrap setup

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following Bootstrap 4 card:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="img/person3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-50 mb-3">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
        <h5 class="text-muted">Editor</h5>
        <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing</p>
        etc...
```

The remainder of the code is irrelevant, and all the code works as intended. However, I'd like to make it so that whenever I hover over a card, the class of `'text-muted'` is removed from the solitary `h5` descendant. I thought I had my jQuery down, so I tried the following:

```
<script>
    $('.card').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('h5').removeClass('.text-muted');
    });
</script>
```

However, this seems to be doing exactly nothing for me, and I can't figure out why. This should find the next `h5` descendant of the hovered-over card and remove the corresponding `text-muted` class from it. Does the fact that there is an `img` and an `h3` sibling before the `h5` have anything to do with this?

How can I accomplish my goal here?

Comment: `doing exactly nothing for me`-> what do you mean by that? class is not removing? or anything thing else you expected?

Comment: I mean quite literally that nothing changes visually by adding this jQuery to my HTML. It is after all my other scripts just prior to the body closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card').hover(function(){
    $('h5', this).removeClass('text-muted');
  }, function(e) {
    $('h5', this).addClass('text-muted');
  });
});
```

Working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card').hover(function(){
   $('h5', this).removeClass('text-muted');
  }, function(e) {
    $('h5', this).addClass('text-muted');
  });
});
```

```css
.text-muted{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <img src="img/person3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-50 mb-3">
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <h5 class="text-muted">Editor</h5>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working jsFiddle link:-https://jsfiddle.net/zuakca4r/

***Note:-***

Your code will work too if your remove `.` from `'.text-muted'` (used in `removeClass()`) .

check this:- https://jsfiddle.net/fc89fmys/

Comment: Bingo. Removing the find did the trick. Why did the find not work?

Comment: @JohnnyApple  your code will work too if your remove `.` from `'.text-muted'` (used in `removeClass()`) .check this:- https://jsfiddle.net/fc89fmys/

Answer (score 0):

Warp your code inside document.ready function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $('.card').hover(function(e){
         $(this).find('h5').removeClass('text-muted');
       }, function(e) {
         $(this).find('h5').addClass('text-muted');
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No visual change using your exact code. I have also never needed a document ready function to enclose my jQuery under my current workflow (using Bootstrap 4 Git Starter Pack with NPM).

Answer (score 0):

When your using removeClass function, don't include '.'. So it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('h5').removeClass('text-muted');
    });
})
```

If you want to add back the class when the mouse leaves, try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('h5').removeClass('text-muted');
    });

    $('.card').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('h5').removeClass('text-muted');
    });

    $('.card').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('h5').addClass('text-muted');
    });
})
```

You can check this here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXqjrK